# How to make use of recursion in preg_replace_callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a JavaScript function (not plain JavaScript)

```
function formatString () {
    var args = jQuery.makeArray(arguments).reverse();
    var str = args.pop();

    return str.replace(/{\d\d*}/g, function () {
       return args.pop();
    }); 
}
```

that I use to format a string e.g
`formatString("{0} and {1}", "first", "second");`
returns `"first and second"`

I want to replicate the same functionality in php and I have the following function:

```
function formatString() {
   if(func_num_args() > 1) {
      $args = array_reverse(func_get_args());
      $input = array_pop($args);
   }
   return preg_replace_callback('/{\d\d*}/', function() use ($args) {
      return array_pop($args);
   }, $input);
}
```

However, in this case `formatString("{0} and {1}", "first", "second");`
returns `"first and first"`

Unlike the JavaScript version of the function where the callback executes for every match, the php variation seems to only execute the callback once.

I am considering making a recursive call to `formatString` as the callback but since preg_replace_callback calls the callback with its own arguments (here in array of matches) I am having a challenge with recursion.

Please advise on how best to utilize the callback or any alternative solution to using `preg_replace_callback`. The use of global variables is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem: PHP is pass-by-value. Consider this:

```
function pop_it($array) {
  array_pop($array);
  print_r($array);
}

$array = array(1, 2);
print_r($array);
// => Array([0] => 1, [1] => 2)

pop_it($array);
// => Array([0] => 1)

print_r($array);
// => Array([0] => 1, [1] => 2)
```

Your function is called just fine. But always with the same argument, since `$args` never changes. Not where it matters - outside the callback. You need pass-by-reference to make the change stick.

Change to `function pop_it(&$array)` (or `use (&$args)`), and... something happens.

However, I do not like this approach, as it will do the wrong thing for `formatString("{1} and {0}", "second", "first")`, as well as for `formatString("{0} and {0}", "only")`. I'd just pluck the index out from the regexp and find it in the array. (Also, `\d\d*` is less legible than, but equivalent to, `\d+`.)

Comment: Thanks highlighting the fact that PHP is pass-by-value. Apparently, modifying to `&$arg` seems to solve the problem and yield the expected result. Please advise why you say it will do the wrong thing for  `formatString("{1} and {0}", "second", "first")`.

Comment: I'd expect it to return `"first and second"`, but it returns `"second and first"`. What's the point of numbers if you are going to ignore them?